# GravCMS - navigation.html.twig dropdown not visible

Tags: html, twig, grav

I've created a new [Pure.css](https://purecss.io/) based Grav theme as described [here](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/theme-tutorial#step-2-create-base-theme).

As they said [here](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/theme-tutorial#step-5-breaking-it-down) at `15.` the dropdown should work by default.
Actually it doesn't for me.

In the rendered page, the navigation looks like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="selected">
    <a href="/">Home </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="/kontakt">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, "Home" should have 3 visible sub-pages.

Does anyone know what could be missing here?

This is the default `partials/navigation.html.twig`:

```html
    {% macro loop(page) %}
        {% for p in page.children.visible %}
            {% set current_page = (p.active or p.activeChild) ? 'selected' : '' %}
            {% if p.children.visible.count > 0 %}
                <li class="has-children {{ current_page }}">
                    <a href="{{ p.url }}">
                        {% if p.header.icon %}<i class="fa fa-{{ p.header.icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
                        {{ p.menu }}
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        {{ _self.loop(p) }}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="{{ current_page }}">
                    <a href="{{ p.url }}">
                        {% if p.header.icon %}<i class="fa fa-{{ p.header.icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
                        {{ p.menu }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endmacro %}

    <ul>
        {% if theme_config.dropdown.enabled %}
            {{ _self.loop(pages) }}
        {% else %}
            {% for page in pages.children.visible %}
                {% set current_page = (page.active or page.activeChild) ? 'selected' : '' %}
                <li class="{{ current_page }}">
                    <a href="{{ page.url }}">
                        {% if page.header.icon %}<i class="fa fa-{{ page.header.icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
                        {{ page.menu }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% for mitem in site.menu %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ mitem.url }}">
                    {% if mitem.icon %}<i class="fa fa-{{ mitem.icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
                    {{ mitem.text }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Yes I should ask that in the GravCMS forums. I registered there 30 days ago but still my account isn't unlocked and no admin answers to my messages. :)

Comment: No way for someone else to figure this out for you. You'll need to determine if your getting the data needed. Enable debugging in twig and start using `{{ dump() }}` for the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in the tutorial...

In line 26 in template `navigation.html.twig`, the variable `theme_config` is being referenced. However, that variable is not a standard Grav variable and is often defined in templates to point to `config.theme`.

To solve your issue, replace `theme_config` in `navigation.html.twig`, by `config.theme` or just `theme`:

```
line 26: {% if config.theme.dropdown.enabled %}
```

The variable `config.theme` points to the file `user/themes/yourtheme/yourtheme.yaml` or to `/user/config/themes/yourtheme.yaml`. The latter is used to override settings from `/user/themes/yourtheme/yourtheme.yaml` and will not be overridden when the theme is updated.

For more info on theme variables see chapter [Theme Variables](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/theme-vars) in Grav's documentation.